# Login Start-Up Problems

Tags: startup

Whenever I log in to my Mac, the following programs automatically open up:  Firefox, Excel, Word, PPT, and VLC Media Player.  I went into System Preferences, Users & Groups, and Login Items, and the only thing in there was the iTunesHelper application.  Any idea on how I can or where I need to go on the Mac to stop these programs from automatically opening up after I log in?

thanks

-Paul

Comment: Are these the programs that you leave open when you shutdown? If so, there's a checkbox that you can deselect when shutting down to prevent them from reopening.

Answer (score 2):

As @Hippo noted, you're probably talking about the OS X Lion feature where programs that are open at shutdown are automatically re-opened at startup unless you uncheck a checkbox when shutting down. Currently, there's no way to unselect that choice via the default UI.

However, a few posters in an [Apple Discussion forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3208633?start=0&tstart=0) have provided some Terminal commands and created AppleScript scripts that can perform this task.

**Terminal Solution**

Scott Nash wrote:

> 1. Open up your `~/Library/Preferencese/ByHost` folder and delete
>      the `com.apple.loginwindow.<long alpha-numeric string>`
> 2. Copy and
>      paste this command into Terminal:
>
>    `defaults write com.apple.loginwindow TALLogoutSavesState 0`
>
> The file you deleted is the one that stores
>   which apps and windows are open. The command directly writes the
>   preference for saving the logout state.
>
> You can read the setting by
>   using this command, although it should reflect the setting in the
>   General System Prefs, now. 
>   `defaults read com.apple.loginwindow` 
>   Look
>   for the line with `TALLogoutSavesState`. It should be `0`, now.
>
> The
>   checkbox in the shutdown dialog will remain checked, but you won't
>   need to change it. It should ignore that since the main preference is
>   set to not save state.

**Script Solution**

Vic07 wrote:

> By using a simple AppleScript application, you can achieve this in a
>   consistent way.
>
> I've compiled an application that after clicking its
>   icon, it will shut down your Mac with "save state" disabled. You can
>   use this app on a daily basis instead of turning the Mac off in the
>   traditional way.   A good idea could be putting it on your Dock so you
>   always have it handy.
>
> You can download the app from [here](http://www.gizmoblurb.com/?p=592)

Later in the discussion, he posts updated versions:

> CleanReboot and CleanShutDown have been updated to 2.0.
>
> This new
>   version is /MUCH/ cleaner than the previous one, since instead of
>   modifying the defaults it makes Finder act like if the user unchecked
>   the save state checkbox and then clicked the Shut Down or Restart
>   button.
>
> [CleanShutDown 2.0](http://www.gizmoblurb.com/?p=592)
>   [CleanReboot 2.0](http://www.gizmoblurb.com/?p=633)

You may want to check out those scripts to see if they address your issue.

One of these two methods may address your issue - I'll have to test it on my Mac after I head home.